# How to remove surfaces smoothly

Tags: modeling, photogrammetry

I am very new to blender and I use it for fine tuning my Photogrammetry.
I scanned the shell below and I want to cut the lower rims evenly round.

[image]

I can use teh Select Circle tool but when I zoom in I still have jagged edges which I want them to be round as shown here:
[image]

So how do I make this cut smooth, which will also cut the existing surfaces adn leave a smooth cut?

Thank you.

Comment: You can smooth the jagged edges with the *Smooth* brush in *Sculpt* mode or the *Mesh Filter > Smooth* brush with a mask, or *Vertices > Smooth Vertices* in *Edit* mode, or use the *Loop Tools* (which might work not that well with such a triangulated mesh)

Comment: You might want to try using Face Sets in Sculpt Mode. Once you have the shell and the surface in an individual Face Set, you can use the Draw Face Set brush while holding down Shift to smooth the edge of the Face Sets. This will alter your geometry and probably distort your UVs, but maybe it will help.

Comment: Thank, I'll try this

Comment: ok, i got it. it is working.
Can i delete the mesh which i mark with the face mask or only hide it? i want to delete...

Comment: To delete the part of a mesh you marked with a Face Set: In sculpt mode hover the cursor over the Face Set that you want to remove, then press H to hide everything except this Face Set. Then go into edit mode and delete the faces. Then press Alt+H to unhide everything and check if you deleted what you want. Note that you probably want to delete faces, not vertices, otherwise you will probably delete to much.